# Hide class variable in PHP so it is not shown in JSON output

Tags: php, json

If I have this code/class in PHP 5.5 that I am putting in a JSON array:

```
# Define the class
class Equip {
  public $var1 = null;
  public $var2 = null;
}

# For debugging purpose only - specify what should be shown
$show_var1 = false;
$show_var2 = true;

while loop ...

  # Initialize a new class member
  $equip = new Equip();

  # Only populate the variable if it should be shown
  if($show_var1) {
    $equip->var1 = $var1;
  }

  # Only populate the variable if it should be shown
  if($show_var2) {
    $equip->var2 = $var2;
  }

  # Populate the JSON array
  $jsonArr[] = $equip;

end while ...

# Output the JSON encoded array
echo json_encode($jsonArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

It will result in this output (where **var1** always is NULL):

```
[
  {
    "var1": null,
    "var2": 656978
},
{
    "var1": null,
    "var2": 136981
}
]
```

How can I hide the **var1** variable from getting in the JSON output?

Comment: How do you actually create the JSON?

Comment: `echo json_encode($jsonArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [`JsonSerializable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface, available in PHP >= 5.4.

If you make your class implement `JsonSerializable`, you can implement a [`jsonSerialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method to return just the data that should be encoded.

```
class Equip implements JsonSerializable {
    public $var1 = null;
    public $var2 = null;
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $out = array();
        if (!is_null($this->var1)) $out['var1'] = $this->var1;
        if (!is_null($this->var2)) $out['var2'] = $this->var2;
        return $out;
    }
}
```

Comment: To me this is clearly the best solution. In fact, I was typing up an answer suggesting the same when I reloaded the page to see this.  Though the original poster indicated he is using PHP 5.5, it should be noted for others who might read this that this requires PHP >= 5.4

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrant I've added a note in my answer about the version.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use array_filter() to remove the NULL or false elements. This should work:

```
# Populate the JSON array
$jsonArr[] = array_filter($equip);
```

See [array_filter() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for more information. Keep in mind, if no callback is passed in, anything that evaluates to FALSE will be removed, so if you plan to store boolean values in $var1 or $var2, this solution won't work.

Note: I do think @jcsanyi's solution is best, however I think this may be the *simplest* way to solve it.

Comment: This could be used within my solution in order to return the right values from the `jsonSerialize()` function.

Comment: I don't like this solution as it can have an unexpected effect on data (cannot return values with 0)

Comment: You can always write your own callback and pass it into array_filter()... You just need to write a function that returns false if the value is null